# How can I have my appSettings.json override my web.Config in .NET core?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-config, appsettings

I need the web.Config for CI CD when I deploy to IIS (for angular routing) but when I run locally and switch environment variables I want it to look at the appSettings. But now when the Web.Config is there it is looking for the env variables there and not the appSettings.json.

Is there someway to say IF I AM RUNNING LOCALLY USE APPSETTINGS AND IGNORE THE WEB.CONFIG ?

Comment: You may provide sample code here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the web.config should not affect the appSettings of ASP.NET Core project.
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configuration-sections-of-webconfig , the appSettings /system.web / connectionStrings / location are ignored by ASP.NET Core app.

Can you share more details about it ?